# Adding a stl file as a product in magento 1.9.0.0

Tags: extensions, magento-1.9

My client wants me to add stl file for new product under 'Manage products' tab. But when I attempt to upload the the stl file in images tab, it shows disallowed file type. I configured my Cms/etc/config.xml file like this....

```
 <extensions>
                    <allowed>
                        <jpg>1</jpg>
                        <jpeg>1</jpeg>
                        <png>1</png>
                        <gif>1</gif>
                        <stl>1</stl>
                    </allowed>
                    <image_allowed>
                        <jpg>1</jpg>
                        <jpeg>1</jpeg>
                        <png>1</png>
                        <gif>1</gif>
                        <stl>1</stl>
                    </image_allowed>
                    <media_allowed>
                        <flv>1</flv>
                        <swf>1</swf>
                        <avi>1</avi>
                        <mov>1</mov>
                        <rm>1</rm>
                        <wmv>1</wmv>
                    </media_allowed>
                </extensions>
```

I even refreshed and flushed cache and logged out and logged in again to admin panel, but it isn't accepting stl files. Any leads? 
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

You should not edit core files since the changes will be lost on the next oficial update, Here is a [guide](http://www.engineer-ing.com/magento/allowingdisallowing-file-extensions-upload-in-the-magento-admin-panel-cms-editor/) to achieve the same without changing core files.

Comment: I used that file, and it had no effects

Comment: In the guide I sent you there is no file to use. You should add that to a config.xml in an extension/module, outside the core codepool.

Comment: Can you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: You should create a [module](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/) and put the code i sent you in the previous link in the config.xml between the config tags in order to make the upload to accept new filetypes.

Comment: I did all, and still it isn't working. I've edited the question and added a screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Create a new module, register it, and add the following into your config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <cms>
            <browser>
                <extensions>
                    <allowed>
                        <stl>1</stl>
                    </allowed>
                </extensions>
            </browser>
        </cms>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Log out of admin, flush caches, and when you log back in you should be able to upload stl's.

Comment: I did it, that module is showing on modules page as enabled.... However I'm unable to upload stl file as an image.